# Straight Line to the lower line in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-trees

As you can see in the picture the line between the second and third level is not straight. What do I need to change in the code to get it straight?
[image]

```
\documentclass[
    12pt, % font size
    a4paper, % paper format
    oneside, % one-sided pages
]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % draw figures
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 0.6cm, thick,
every node/.style = {rectangle, font=\sffamily\normalsize , white,
    top color = punct, bottom color = punct,
    text width = 3cm, align = center, minimum height = 2.4cm}]
% First Level
\node (Projektleiter) {\textbf{Projektleiter}\\Severin};
\coordinate [below = 2cm of Projektleiter] (second);
% Second Level
\node (Stv-Projektleiter) [left  = 2mm of second]  {\textbf{Stv. Projektleiter}\\Pascal};
\coordinate [below = 1cm of Stv-Projektleiter] (third);
% Third Level
\node (Informatik) [below = of third] {\textbf{Leiter Informatik}\\Jonas};
\node (Elektrotechnik) [left = of Informatik] {\textbf{Leiter Elektrotechnik}\\Manuel};
\node (Maschinenbau) [right = of Informatik] {\textbf{Leiter Maschinenbau}\\Roman};
\node (Redaktion) [right = of Maschinenbau] {\textbf{Redaktorin}\\Sindi};
\coordinate [below = 1cm of Informatik] (fourth);
% Fourth Level
\node (Stv-Maschinenbau) [below = of Maschinenbau] {\textbf{Stv. Maschinenbau}\\Valentin};
\draw [delim,thick]
(Projektleiter) -- (second) -- (Stv-Projektleiter)
(Projektleiter) -- (second) -- (third) -| (Informatik)
(third) -| (Elektrotechnik)
(third) -| (Maschinenbau)
(third) -| (Redaktion)
(Maschinenbau) -- (Stv-Maschinenbau);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `\node (Stv-Projektleiter)` is listed as `left` of your `second` coordinate, and by extension it is left of `Projecktleiter`. A quick adjustment to `\node (Stv-Projektleiter) [below = 2mm of second]` straightens the line out, but I'm sure you'll want to make some other adjustments.

Comment: Thanks, the line is now straight but goes over the one box... Can I change that also?

Comment: Another option is to adjust the `(Projektleiter) -- (second) -- (third) -| (Informatik)` line to `(second) |- (third)`. Is this more in line with what you were asking?

Comment: Oh, but if *that* is the fix you're looking for, ignore my original comment and revert to the original `(Stv-Projektleiter)` position of `left`.

Comment: Yes, now it looks good, I also changed the line `\node (Stv-Projektleiter) [below, left = 2mm of second]  {\textbf{Stv. Projektleiter}\\Pascal};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in the fourth level instead of having `(Projektleiter) -- (second) -- (third) -| (Informatik)` it should had been `(Projektleiter) -- (second) |- (third) -- (Informatik)`

```
\documentclass[
12pt, % font size
a4paper, % paper format
oneside, % one-sided pages
]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % draw figures
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
auto, node distance=0.6cm,thick,
every node/.style={rectangle,font=\sffamily\normalsize,white, top color=punct,bottom color=punct,text width=3cm, align=center,minimum height=2.4cm}]
% First Level
\node (Projektleiter) {\textbf{Projektleiter}\\Severin};
\coordinate [below = 2cm of Projektleiter] (second);
% Second Level
\node (Stv-Projektleiter) [left=2mm of second]  {\textbf{Stv. Projektleiter}\\Pascal};
\coordinate [below = 1cm of Stv-Projektleiter] (third);
% Third Level
\node (Informatik) [below = of third] {\textbf{Leiter Informatik}\\Jonas};
\node (Elektrotechnik) [left = of Informatik] {\textbf{Leiter Elektrotechnik}\\Manuel};
\node (Maschinenbau) [right = of Informatik] {\textbf{Leiter Maschinenbau}\\Roman};
\node (Redaktion) [right = of Maschinenbau] {\textbf{Redaktorin}\\Sindi};
\coordinate [below = 1cm of Informatik] (fourth);
% Fourth Level
\node (Stv-Maschinenbau) [below = of Maschinenbau] {\textbf{Stv. Maschinenbau}\\Valentin};
\draw [delim,thick]
(Projektleiter) -- (second) -- (Stv-Projektleiter)
(Projektleiter) -- (second) |- (third) -- (Informatik)
(third) -| (Elektrotechnik)
(third) -| (Maschinenbau)
(third) -| (Redaktion)
(Maschinenbau) -- (Stv-Maschinenbau);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A (very) different way how to draw your *tree*. By using `trees` TikZ library this is quite simple with very concise code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, 
               border=3mm, many
              ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadings, trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%auto, thick,
          node distance = 3mm,
      every node/.style = {rectangle, fill=punct, font=\sffamily, text=white,
                           text width = 3cm, minimum height = 2.2cm,
                           align = flush center},
edge from parent/.style = {draw=delim, thick},
         level distance = 32mm,
       sibling distance = 34mm,
edge from parent fork down
                     ]
% First Level
\node (Projektleiter) {\textbf{Projektleiter}\\Severin}
% Second Level (only for coordinate)
    child{ node[coordinate] (second) {}
% Third Level
        child{ node {\textbf{Leiter Informatik}\\Jonas}}
        child{ node {\textbf{Leiter Elektrotechnik}\\Manuel}}
        child{ node {\textbf{Leiter Maschinenbau}\\Roman}
% Fourth Level
            child{ node {\textbf{Stv. Maschinenbau}\\Valentin}}}
% Third Level
        child{ node {\textbf{Redaktorin}\\Sindi}}
        };
% Second Level
\node [left=of second] (Stv-Projektleiter) {\textbf{Stv. Projektleiter}\\Pascal};
\draw [delim,thick] (Stv-Projektleiter) -- (second);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Even more concise code can be obtain with `forest` package, however, I still not mastered it.

As follows from picture, I slightly modified nodes, for fill I used just `fill=punct`, define `normalsize` for font is surplus and `minimum height=22mm` is (to my taste) sufucient ...

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is a nice approach.